Notification Service
Problem Statement
I've implemented a notification service for an application system. The service needs to handle different types of notifications (currently only application submission) and send them to various recipients (candidate, organization user, and networker) using the Novu API. The implementation should be flexible enough to easily add new notification types and recipient roles in the future.
Solution
My solution consists of three main parts:

An abstract base class NotificationService that defines the interface for notification services.
A set of data models and templates for notifications using Pydantic.
A concrete implementation NovuNotificationService that uses the Novu API to bulk send notifications.

Code



import abc


class NotificationService(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def application_submit(self, candidate_id: str, org_user_id: str, networker_id: str, **kwargs):
        pass




from enum import Enum, auto

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class NotificationType(Enum):
    APPLICATION_SUBMITTED = auto()
    # Add other notification types here


class RecipientRole(Enum):
    CANDIDATE = auto()
    ORG_USER = auto()
    NETWORKER = auto()


class NotificationContent(BaseModel):
    body: str
    subject: str
    primary_action_label: str
    secondary_action_label: str
    primary_action_url: str
    secondary_action_url: str
    redirect_url: str
    avatar: str
    channels: dict[str, bool] = Field(default_factory=dict)
    target: str = ""

    class Config:
        # This allows additional attributes to be set dynamically
        extra = "allow"


class NotificationTemplate(BaseModel):
    content: NotificationContent
    dynamic_fields: set[str] = Field(default_factory=set)


NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATES: dict[NotificationType, dict[RecipientRole, NotificationTemplate]] = {
    NotificationType.APPLICATION_SUBMITTED: {
        RecipientRole.CANDIDATE: NotificationTemplate(
            content=NotificationContent(
                body="Your application for {job_title} has been submitted successfully.",
                subject="Application Submitted for {job_title}",
                primary_action_label="View Application",
                secondary_action_label="View Job Details",
                redirect_url='',
                primary_action_url='{application_url}',
                secondary_action_url='{job_url}',
                avatar='{candidate_avatar}',
            ),
            dynamic_fields={"job_title", "application_url", "job_url", "candidate_avatar"}
        ),
        RecipientRole.ORG_USER: NotificationTemplate(
            content=NotificationContent(
                body="A new application for {job_title} has been received from {candidate_name}.",
                subject="New Application Received for {job_title}",
                primary_action_label="View Application",
                secondary_action_label="View All Applications",
                redirect_url='',
                primary_action_url='{application_url}',
                secondary_action_url='{all_applications_url}',
                avatar='{org_user_avatar}',
            ),
            dynamic_fields={"job_title", "candidate_name", "application_url", "all_applications_url", "org_user_avatar"}
        ),
        RecipientRole.NETWORKER: NotificationTemplate(
            content=NotificationContent(
                body="Your referral {candidate_name} has submitted an application for {job_title}.",
                subject="Referral Application Submitted for {job_title}",
                primary_action_label="View Candidate Profile",
                secondary_action_label="View Job Details",
                redirect_url='',
                primary_action_url='{candidate_profile_url}',
                secondary_action_url='{job_url}',
                avatar='{networker_avatar}',
            ),
            dynamic_fields={"candidate_name", "job_title", "candidate_profile_url", "job_url", "networker_avatar"}
        )
    }
}




import os
from typing import ClassVar, Iterable, Any

from novu.api import EventApi
from novu.dto.event import InputEventDto

from .notification.abc import NotificationService
from .notification.template import NotificationContent, NotificationType, RecipientRole, NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATES


NOVU_API_URL = "https://api.novu.co"
NOVU_API_KEY  = os.environ["NOVU_API_KEY"]


class NovuNotificationService(NotificationService):

    WORKFLOW_NAME: ClassVar[str] = "generic-notification"

    def __init__(self, api_url: str = NOVU_API_URL, api_key: str = NOVU_API_KEY):
        self.event_api: EventApi = EventApi(api_url, api_key)

    def _build_event(self, recipient: str, content: NotificationContent) -> InputEventDto:
        return InputEventDto(
            name=self.WORKFLOW_NAME,
            recipients=recipient,
            payload={
                'body': content.body,
                'channels': content.channels,
                'subject': content.subject,
                'avatar': content.avatar,
                'redirect': {
                    'url': content.redirect_url,
                    'target': content.target
                },
                'primaryAction': {
                    'label': content.primary_action_label,
                    'redirect': {
                        'url': content.primary_action_url,
                        'target': content.target
                    }
                },
                'secondaryAction': {
                    'label': content.secondary_action_label,
                    'redirect': {
                        'url': content.secondary_action_url,
                        'target': content.target
                    }
                }
            }
        )

    def _bulk_send(self, events: Iterable[InputEventDto]) -> None:
        self.event_api.trigger_bulk(events=list(events))
        

    def _iter_events(
        self,
        _type: NotificationType,
        recipients: dict[RecipientRole, str],
        dynamic_content: dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Iterable[InputEventDto]:
        for role, recipient_id in recipients.items():
            template = NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATES[_type][role]
            content = NotificationContent(**template.content.model_dump())
            for field in template.dynamic_fields:
                if field in dynamic_content:
                    setattr(content, field, dynamic_content[field])

            # Format string fields with dynamic content
            for field, value in content.dict().items():
                if isinstance(value, str):
                    setattr(content, field, value.format(**dynamic_content))

            yield self._build_event(recipient_id, content)

    def send_notification(
        self,
        _type: NotificationType,
        recipients: dict[RecipientRole, str],
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        events = self._iter_events(_type, recipients, kwargs)
        self._bulk_send(events)

    def application_submit(self, candidate_id: str, org_user_id: str, networker_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.send_notification(
            _type=NotificationType.APPLICATION_SUBMITTED,
            recipients={
                RecipientRole.CANDIDATE: candidate_id,
                RecipientRole.ORG_USER: org_user_id,
                RecipientRole.NETWORKER: networker_id
            },
            **kwargs
        )

Self Analysis
Self-Analysis and Potential Improvements

The NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATES dictionary is a large, nested structure that could become difficult to manage as more notification types and recipient roles are added.
No error handling
Lack of Testing
No doc-strings


start small
Kudos on implementing (almost) the simplest thing that could
possibly work. You have a nice solid base to branch out from.
But maybe we're getting fancy slightly prematurely.
Only a single class, NovuNotificationService, uses
that abstract class, so we might have waited until
there's a second caller before going abstract.
I encourage you to add a second "stub" Enum value,
to justify having a NotificationType class.
I worry that class Config has perhaps been introduced
a bit prematurely. You might wait until a Requirement
forces you to deal with alternate configurations.
Let your unit tests drive such decisions.
mixin
    def application_submit( ...
        self.send_notification( ...

We have essentially a
façade
here. Given the inheritance, I was slightly surprised
this doesn't start with a super() call.
Now, I know this directly inherits from a no-op abstract class,
so it won't alter the execution.
But I worry about some maintenance engineer a year from now
who will copy-n-paste into some new class without thinking.
In the Public API you are designing, it does not appear to me
you wanted to expose that helper to random callers.
Consider using a _private name for it: _send_notification().
optional type annotation
Thank you for explaining we have three str inputs.
As long you're annotating, may as well point out
that we "evaluate for side effects" and always return None.
    def application_submit( ... ) -> None:

That enables the use of additional helpful tooling,
such as $ mypy --strict *.py
methods are verbs
Class names are nouns, while {functions, methods} use verbs.
Here Master Yoda seems to be starting with a noun,
and then we get around to the action word of "submit!".
Recommend you swap the order, submit_application(),
for a less stilted phrasing.
no shadowing
        self.send_notification(
            _type=NotificationType.APPLICATION_SUBMITTED,

Ok, you didn't want to shadow the builtin type(), that's good.
But the conventional approach here would be a suffix, type_,
rather than a _private prefix.
dataclass

The NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATES dictionary is a large, nested structure that could become difficult to manage

I'm not super worried about that.
Rely on from pprint import pp when you're debugging such data structures.
Consider using glom
to access deeply nested dicts.
You could make each template a dataclass.
They nest nicely.
And they type check.
You can add arbitrary validation or debugging methods to such a class.
exceptions

No error handling

I don't see that as a problem.
If an exception happens, it will bubble up the call stack,
until someone deals with it.
By default, the cPython interpreter will give a nice
diagnostic stack trace.
If you later add a Requirement to your Specification document
which involves recovering from some common error,
fine, you can deal with it then.
The current code performs adequately as-is.
automated test suite

Lack of Testing

Yeah, that's a giant red flag.
I am finding this codebase hard to read.
Why, because it is badly written? No.
The trouble is I don't have a motivating Use Case
which helps me navigate down through the call stack.
If you had supplied a unit test which (eventually)
exercises the app submit method, that would have
guided my reading. I would have gradually encountered
new concepts, branched out to read about them, and
resume where I left off.
As it stands, you're asking me to read a lot of un-motivated
code in the hope that at some later time I will find it useful.
And you will want some unit tests
when you get around to refactoring,
or adding a second inheriting class.
no docstrings
That's not necessarily a problem, if method name + signature
makes it obvious what the method should do.
Writing at least a one-sentence docstring is essential
for any abstract methods.
By definition there's nothing to see there,
nothing to explain what the method does.
We need a specification of what it does,
so that each engineer who writes an implementation
conforming to that spec will know they have implemented correctly.
optional values
class NotificationContent(BaseModel):
    ...
    secondary_action_label: str
    ...
    secondary_action_url: str ...

For the primary label and url, insisting on a string value makes perfect sense.
For the secondaries, it's not obvious to me that your Use Case
actually requires values in all circumstances.
(I don't know, as the OP doesn't explain such details.)
I'm concerned an implementor might be tempted to
use an "" empty-string sentinel value.
Maybe that's fine. Or maybe None would make
more sense, in which case annotate with ...: str | None
naming
class NotificationTemplate(BaseModel):
    ...
    dynamic_fields: set[str] = ...

Is it "dynamic"? Yes.
Do we need to be reminded of that with each use? Probably not.
Prefer just fields: set[str] ..., and explain the
details in a # comment or """docstring""" as warranted.
Or maybe required_fields would be more descriptive?
side effects at import time
NOVU_API_KEY  = os.environ["NOVU_API_KEY"]

No, please don't do that.
It's an anti-pattern.
The unit test I will implement next week
which tests some small detail like WORKFLOW_NAME
will blow up with KeyError during import unless I have specified an (irrelevant) API key.
Supplying the key as an env var is the Right Thing.
But don't bomb out until the point where you actually need the key.
We could use getenv() or .get() here, possibly producing None.
But it's probably better to defer examining the env var
until we're running code which needs it.
A def _get_novu_api_key() helper might make sense here.

Thanks for the time and effort. You also got a chuckle out of me with the Master Yoda bit.
